# On storing value to ViewState issue is coming

Tags: c#, asp.net, class, viewstate

I am placing my above code in the screen shot as [image]

The error screenshot is 
[image]

On placing this line I mean storing value to viewstate issue is coming, on deleting this line issue get resolves.

[image]

Whats the issue I dont know, Please suggest

Comment: You have to mark your class **Serializable**. Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7574976/how-to-store-an-object-in-the-viewstate)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error says, you need to mark your `CommissionDistributionInfo` class with the [Serializable] attribute.

```
[Serializable]
public class CommissionDistributionInfo
{
    // implementation...
}
```

Comment: please change name instead of [Serlializable] to [Serializable]

Comment: Thanks. Sorry about the typo.